# RegEx - Parse through string for specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to parse through a string and find all the handles (@*name*) and push them each into one array (without the `@` though) so I can loop through them (with `forEach`) and send them each an alert. Each handle is separated by a space.

[image: Message example]

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
let str= "Here @ann and @john go to @jane";

let m= str.match(/@\w+/g).map(x=>x.replace(/./,''));
                              
m.forEach(x=> console.log(x));
```

You can use also positive lookbehind regexp but it is not supported by firefox [yet](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_Lookbehind_Assertions) (but it is part of ES2018):

```js
let str= "Here @ann and @john go to @jane";

let m= str.match(/(?<=@)\w+/g);

m.forEach(x=> console.log(x));
```

where `(?<=@)\w+` match word which start after @ (excluding this char - [positive lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html))

Comment: I'm getting in error when I open my web page up now in Firefox, but it's still working fine in Chrome. The Firefox error is: `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`

Answer (score 2):

You can capture `@followedByName` and than replace `@`

```js
let str = `@someName hey @someMoreNames`

let op = str.match(/(^|\s)@\w+/g).map(e=>e.trim().replace(/@/g,''))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to extract the users from a tweet, you can use the following regex:

```
/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g
```

For example:

```
var string = '@JohnSmith @DylanThompson Hey guys!';
var numberPattern = /@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

var res = string.match(numberPattern);

console.log(res);
```

This would spit out:

```
["@JohnSmith", "@DylanThompson"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `match` to extract names and `slice` to remove `@`:

```js
str = "@JohnSmith @DylanThompson Hey guys";
let arr = str.match(/@\w+/g).map(e=>e.slice(1));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var str= "Here @ann and @john go to @jane";
var patt = /@(\w+)/g;

while ( (arr = patt.exec(str)) !== null ) { console.log(arr[1]); }
```